# Azure DevOps REST API call to Accounts-endpoint retrieves TF400813 error

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to read all accounts my user is associated with. The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/account/accounts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) claims that this should be possible by calling:

```
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?api-version=5.1
```

Because the docs are kind of confusing it could be that I have to call

```
GET https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?ownerId={GUID}&api-version=5.1
```

instead.

I'm using [OAuth-Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops). In order to get it work I created an ASP.NET Core application. I created an app registration in DevOps and I retrieve an OAuth token with the following scopes without any problem:

- vso.auditlog
- vso.connected_server
- vso.dashboards
- vso.entitlements
- vso.environment_manage
- vso.graph
- vso.identity
- vso.loadtest
- vso.machinegroup_manage
- vso.memberentitlementmanagement
- **vso.profile**
- vso.project
- vso.securefiles_read
- vso.security_manage
- vso.taskgroups_read
- vso.tokenadministration
- vso.tokens
- vso.variablegroups_read
- vso.wiki

According to the docs only `vso.profile` should be necessary for this request.

However the result I receive is always:

```
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (TF400813: The user '{AZURE_TENANT_ID}\{MY_MAIL_ADDRESS}' is not authorized to access this resource.).
```

Other requests are working just fine e.g.:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1
```

The accounts-request is special because it can be sent without setting the context to a specific organisation or project. I guess this the reason for the different results.

**EDIT**

After trying ot today using the both URLs mentioned above I now get `400` as the response status code. This is a sample Bearer-Token I got after I decoded it:

```json
{
    "nameid": "1340eb0b-cabf-476c-a950-a070c34ca367",
    "scp": "vso.profile",
    "aui": "a2d8bdf0-9406-415a-aa79-bee9e2600c37",
    "appid": "e1bea2a2-****-****-****-************",
    "iss": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
    "aud": "app.vstoken.visualstudio.com",
    "nbf": 1587395030,
    "exp": 1587398630
}
```

Here is some simplified C# code I use:

```csharp
HttpClient client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("DevOps");
var token = await _authHelper.GetTokenAsync(tokenType);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer { token.AccessToken}");
var uri = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?api-version = 5.1";
try
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // ex.Message = Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
    // ...
    throw;
}
```

Comment: The wired things is it work fine for me. Is it convenient to share the detailed c# project you used? Are you using the sample project that our github provided?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I added some sample code.